# I want a variant of this list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 10 transactions with properties shares and size. I want the sum of each of these. Is there a way to do it in one loop instead of 2?

How I achieve this now:

```
total_shares = sum((t.shares for t in transactions))
total_size   = sum((t.size for t in transactions))
```

Comment: Do you think is one loop may change anything instead of 2? Codes looks fine I think.

Comment: Note that you have extra parenthesis in your code.  You could just do: `sum(t.shares for t in transactions)`, since the parenthesis for `sum()` enclose the generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. `sum` function can find the sum of only one iterable at a time. So, you either need to change your code like this

```
total_shares, total_size = 0, 0

for t in transactions:
    total_shares, total_size = total_shares + t.shares, total_size + t.size
```

Or be happy with the code which you have already shown in the question. That is perfect and nothing wrong in it.

If you really like to complicate your code, you can change it into this

```
t_shares, t_size = map(sum, zip(*((t.shares, t.size) for t in transactions))))
```

This get first generate tuples with `shares` and `sizes` and then `zip` will transform the tuples into two tuples of `shares` and `sizes` and finally `sum` will be applied to each of the tuples which will be unpacked over `t_shares` and `t_size`.

**Note:** The `map`, `sum` and `zip` variation actually runs more loops internally than the explicit two loops like you have shown in your question.

Comment: I was going to suggest the `map sum zip` variation. I would point out that it does not really reduce the number of loops, though

Comment: Or `map(sum, zip(*map(attrgetter('shares', 'size'), transactions)))` to get really functional. :)

Comment: I'm going to refuse to post `s = sum(t.shares+t.size*1j for t in transactions); total_shares, total_size = s.real, s.imag` as an answer because it's insane..

Comment: @DSM lol, I saw that answer in a canon question. That is real evil... :D

Comment: People use it on codegolf..  Which is the whole point, really: there's no native way to do this, so as you say, we write the loop, we wrap it in a function if we really care, and we get on with our day..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go full functional, toss in a `map` with your `reduce`:

```
import operator
reduce(lambda *tups: map(operator.add, *tups), ((t.shares, t.size) for t in transactions))
```

Though, if you only have 10 transactions, it's not like it really matters how many passes you do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and write your own addition operator:

```
from functools import reduce

def add_transaction(x, y):
    # exact details here depend on what a transaction contains
    return Transaction(shares=x.shares + y.shares,
                       size=x.size + y.size)

total_shares, total_size = reduce(add_transaction, transactions)
```

No bets on whether this is an improvement though.  It might even be a pessimization.

Comment: FYI, `reduce` is also available as a builtin on Python 2. It only got moved out of the main namespace as part of Python 3

Comment: @njzk2: You're right, I forgot the OP changed the datatype from a pair to a "transaction".